# How get the nr of rows until the next value

Tags: python, performance, numpy

What would be an efficient way to get the nr of rows until the next signal value in numpy?

I have a list of signal values (-1, nan, 1) which looks similar to this table below and would like to get another list with the nr of rows value until the next signal. Taking into account the negative and positive values.

Given the second column of this table, `signal`, I want to produce the third column, `backward`:

```
+-------+--------+----------+
| index | signal | backward |
+-------+--------+----------+
|     0 |        |          |
|     1 |        |          |
|     2 |        |          |
|     3 |      1 |        4 |
|     4 |        |        3 |
|     5 |        |        2 |
|     6 |        |        1 |
|     7 |     -1 |       -3 |
|     8 |        |       -2 |
|     9 |        |       -1 |
|    10 |      1 |        3 |
|    11 |        |        2 |
|    12 |        |        1 |
|    13 |      1 |        5 |
|    14 |        |        4 |
|    15 |        |        3 |
|    16 |        |        2 |
|    17 |        |        1 |
|    18 |     -1 |       -3 |
|    19 |        |       -2 |
|    20 |        |       -1 |
|    21 |     -1 |       -5 |
|    22 |        |       -4 |
|    23 |        |       -3 |
|    24 |        |       -2 |
|    25 |        |       -1 |
|    26 |      1 |        4 |
|    27 |        |        3 |
|    28 |        |        2 |
|    29 |        |        1 |
+-------+--------+----------+
```

the shape of the original numpy looks something like this. Please excuse the way i create this random list, i do not know any better way :) It is just for demonstration purposes

```
import numpy as np
data = np.random.randint(-4, 4, (1000,)).astype(float)
data[data == -2] = 'nan'
data[data == -3] = 'nan'
data[data == -4] = 'nan'
data[data == 0] = 'nan'
data[data == 2] = 'nan'
data[data == 3] = 'nan'
print(data)
```

The size of it is a few millions, so it has to be as efficient as possible

Comment: your randint call will never return 1 - are you sure that is correct?

Comment: i just fix it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one approach based on cumulative summation -

```
def seq_descending(a):
    mask = ~np.isnan(a)
    idx = np.flatnonzero(mask)
    shift_idx = np.hstack((idx[1:] - idx[:-1], a.size - idx[-1] ))

    out = -np.ones(a.size, dtype=int)
    out[idx] = shift_idx-1
    idx0 = idx[0]

    out[:idx0] = 0
    out[idx0] += 1

    cumsums = out.cumsum()
    signs = np.repeat(a[idx].astype(int), shift_idx)
    cumsums[idx0:] *= signs

    return cumsums
```

Sample run -

1) Setup input array :

```
In [82]: a = np.full((30,), np.nan)
    ...: a[[3,7,10,13,18,21,26]] = [1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1]
    ...:
```

2) Get output array and stack against input for comparison :

```
In [83]: np.column_stack((a, seq_descending(a) ))
Out[83]: 
array([[ nan,   0.],
       [ nan,   0.],
       [ nan,   0.],
       [  1.,   4.],
       [ nan,   3.],
       [ nan,   2.],
       [ nan,   1.],
       [ -1.,  -3.],
       [ nan,  -2.],
       [ nan,  -1.],
       [  1.,   3.],
       [ nan,   2.],
       [ nan,   1.],
       [  1.,   5.],
       [ nan,   4.],
       [ nan,   3.],
       [ nan,   2.],
       [ nan,   1.],
       [ -1.,  -3.],
       [ nan,  -2.],
       [ nan,  -1.],
       [ -1.,  -5.],
       [ nan,  -4.],
       [ nan,  -3.],
       [ nan,  -2.],
       [ nan,  -1.],
       [  1.,   4.],
       [ nan,   3.],
       [ nan,   2.],
       [ nan,   1.]])
```

Comment: You are a true supporter :) I cannot thank you enough for all your answers to my questions. I really appreciate your dedication to this community

Comment: @RaduS Appreciate the kind words :)

Answer (score 1):

**Data:**

```
array([ nan,  -1.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,
        nan,   1.,  -1.,  nan,  -1.,  -1.,  nan,  nan,  -1.])
```

You can use `pandas` for this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':np.square(np.nan_to_num(data)).cumsum(),'signal':data})

df['backward'] = df.groupby('id')['id'].transform(lambda x: np.arange(1, len(x)+1)[::-1])

df['backward'] = df['backward']*df.signal.fillna(method='ffill')

>>> df
    id  signal  backward
0    0     NaN       NaN
1    1      -1       -11
2    1     NaN       -10
3    1     NaN        -9
4    1     NaN        -8
5    1     NaN        -7
6    1     NaN        -6
7    1     NaN        -5
8    1     NaN        -4
9    1     NaN        -3
10   1     NaN        -2
11   1     NaN        -1
12   2       1         1
13   3      -1        -2
14   3     NaN        -1
15   4      -1        -1
16   5      -1        -3
17   5     NaN        -2
18   5     NaN        -1
19   6      -1        -1
```

Comment: I was actually doing it with pandas at the moment but it was too slow, i was using a different approach. Thank you anyway for the answer :)